# print function and parenthesis what is happening?

Tags: php

surprisingly these are different and I cannot understand what is going on:

```
var_dump(print'2');
echo "<br>";
var_dump((print '2')+3);
echo "<br>";
var_dump(print '2'+3);
echo "<br>";
echo '1'.(print '2')+3;
```

here is the output:

```
2int(1) 
2int(4) 
5int(1) 
214
```

I know that print function outputs a string and this string is a number so it it showing me an integer as a value but I don't exactly understand what's happening here would someone please explain it?
why +3 doesn't affect in line 2? why the vardump amount is different?

Comment: Fun question with interesting differences! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For line #1

```
print '2'
```

prints `2` and returns a `1` value that is then var_dumped() as `int(1)`

For line #2

```
print '2'
```

prints `2` and returns a `1` value that is then added to `3` before being var_dumped() as `int(4)`

For line #3

```
print '2'+3
```

prints `5` (the sum of `2` and `3`) and returns a `1` value that is then var_dumped() as `int(1)`

for line #4

```
(print '2')
```

prints `2` and returns a `1` which is added to `3` giving `4`; the echo then outputs `1` followed the result of that sum (`4`)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php):

> Returns *1*, always.

---

To your examples:

- `var_dump(print'2');` will print the string `2` and return/dump the integer `1`.
- `var_dump((print '2')+3);` will print the string `2` and return/dump the integer `1` + `3`.
- `var_dump(print '2'+3);` will print `'2' + 3`, which evaluates to `5`, and then return/dump the integer `1`.
- `echo '1'.(print '2')+3;` will print `2` and then echo `1` concatenated with sum of `1`, from `print '2'`, and `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the [`php docs for print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)

> Print outputs the argument passed to it and always returns 1.

So below outputs are

```
var_dump(print'2'); 
// outputs two and gives int 1 to vardump
var_dump((print '2')+3);
// outputs 2 and adds 3 to retuned 1 to pass 4 to vardump
var_dump(print '2'+3);
//prints 2+3=5 and gives 1 to var_dump
echo '1'.(print '2')+3; 
// prints 2 first then 1 is concatinated with 4 which is sum of 3 and 1 from print
```